# Environment variable is not assigning with Typescript

Tags: typescript

My code is:

```
const port: Number = process.env.PORT || 3000;

[ts]
Type 'string | 3000' is not assignable to type 'Number'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Number'.
```

I tried

```
const port: Number = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
```

But it gives me another error:

```
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
(property) NodeJS.Process.env: NodeJS.ProcessEnv
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's complaining about the argument you're passing to `parseInt`, which may be undefined but must be a string. I think you want `parseInt(process.env.PORT || '3000', 10)`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
const port: Number = parseInt(<string>process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
```

This solved it. I think it's called [Type Assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html)

Comment: I think that's not correct? `process.env.PORT` could be string, or it could be undefined. You're asserting that it can't be undefined here which is false. As the comment-answer above says, you should  `parseInt(process.env.PORT || '3000')` to cover the case when `process.env.PORT` is undefined.

Comment: You can also do:
`const port: Number = parseInt(\`${process.env.PORT}\`, 10) || 3000`
which will ensure a string is passed to parseInt.

Answer (score 3):

I usually do this.

```
const PORT = Number(process.env.PORT ?? 3000);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

This should work as well.

```js
const port: Number = parseInt(process.env.PORT as string, 10) || 3000
```