# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number' for environment variable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I can't understand this.  I even set it as a string in the .env file!

**.env**

`POSTGRES_PORT=5432`

**DB.tsx**

```js
const postgresClient = new Client({
    user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    password: process.env.POSTGRES_PWD,
    port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
});
```

[image]

I've tried this but didn't matter:
`POSTGRES_PORT="5432"`

Also tried `process.env.POSTGRES_PORT.toString()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Environment variable is not assigning with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376419/environment-variable-is-not-assigning-with-typescript)

Comment: Everything in `process.env` is a string; your "port" property is declared as a number, so you have to convert that string to a number: `port: +process.env.POSTGRES_PORT`

Comment: thanks didn't know I could use a `+` to turn it to a number, figured I'd have to use parseInt

Comment: @PositiveGuy That's just as fine. Even better actually, as a port should be an integer not an arbitrary floating point number.